# Kicking off monitors from a main java program

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium-webdriver

I have a java program that checks a database every minute, to see if a certain website needs to be monitored. If it meets the condition, I pass the website URL into my other java program (runnable jar) using ProcessBuilder... and it monitors the website as I would expect.

However, this seems to be causing huge memory leaks. I seem to get a "Java out of memory exception", even when only a few websites are being monitored... and I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this, than calling a JAR from within a JAR.

This is how I currently kick off a website monitor:

```
if(URL.length() > 1) {

        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "/usr/opt/monitor/Monitor.jar", URL);
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        builder.redirectOutput(new File("/usr/opt/logs/Monitor.log"));
        Process p = builder.start();
```

Can anyone please suggest a better way of achieving this please? Threading? Calling the class from Monitor.jar directly?

Comment: First of all you need to find source of memory leak. And only then try to fix it.

Comment: If one of your requirement is to have separate apps, you could make a use of a JMS Queue to which your app would publish a message everytime a website needs to be monitored and have another app subscribing to this queue and that would create a thread (with your monitoring logic) for each message it receives.

Comment: Each process has its own memory space, so you will need to check which process is causing the out of memory and need to analyse that application and I think it has nothing to do with the way the monitor process is started.

Answer (score 0):

Each process causes significant memory overhead. The simplest way to get rid of processes is to run the method `main(String[])` of the main class of the jar file directly in the calling process in a separate thread. To limit the number of threads running simultaneously it is worth-while to use a thread pool with fixed number of threads, otherwise you can run out of memory because of accidental increase of number of URLs to process.

If these measures won't take effect, then you have memory leak inside the monitoring program.